# Database Design feedback

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

An invoice can contain 1 or more orders, how to archive this?

**Example of Invoice:**

```
OrderID |      Order Date    |   Amount
   31            10/02/2011         £1.50
   43            12/02/2011         £1.50
   74            13/02/2011         £5.00
                                   =======
                            Total   £8.00
```

If the Total is minus (eg: -8.00), it mean client owes me money. 
Without minus, I pay client some money.

Here what I came up with:

**Orders Table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `orders` (
  `OrderID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Total` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,
  `OrderDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `Status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `userID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `InvoiceID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`OrderID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

**Invoice Table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `invoice` (
  `InvoiceID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `InvoiceDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `Amount` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,
  `Status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`InvoiceID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

invoice.Status (0 Processing, 1 Invoice Sent, 2 Cancelled, 3 Completed)
or what better status can be?

**Payment Table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `payment` (
  `PaymentID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `InvoiceID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Amount` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,
  `DatePayment` datetime NOT NULL,
  `PaymentType` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PaymentID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

payment.PaymentType = (1: Payment Received From Customer (Owes Money), 2: Payment Sent To Customer)

**Database Result:**

```
mysql> select * from orders;
+---------+-------+---------------------+--------+--------+-----------+
| OrderID | Total | OrderDate           | Status | userID | InvoiceID |
+---------+-------+---------------------+--------+--------+-----------+
|       1 | 20.00 | 2011-06-18 15:51:51 |      1 |    123 |         1 |
|       2 | 10.00 | 2011-06-19 15:51:57 |      1 |    123 |         1 |
|       3 |  5.00 | 2011-06-20 15:52:00 |      1 |    123 |         1 |
+---------+-------+---------------------+--------+--------+-----------+

mysql> select * from invoice;
+-----------+---------------------+--------+--------+
| InvoiceID | InvoiceDate         | Amount | Status |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+--------+
|         1 | 2011-06-30 15:55:21 |  35.00 |      1 |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+--------+

mysql> select * from payment;
+-----------+-----------+--------+---------------------+-------------+
| PaymentID | InvoiceID | Amount | DatePayment         | PaymentType |
+-----------+-----------+--------+---------------------+-------------+
|         1 |         1 |  35.00 | 2011-06-29 15:56:16 |           1 |
+-----------+-----------+--------+---------------------+-------------+
```

Im I on the right path? What can be improved/changed or suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: It looks okay - I would suggest that having `Status` on both `orders` and `invoices` is a little confusing.  If orders can have a status independent of the invoice, then it would be okay.

Comment: Thanks for including schema in your original question. Many people don't. I don't see them defined here, so don't forget to index your foreign keys (`orders.userID`, `orders.InvoiceID`, `payment.InvoiceID`).

Comment: Depending on how costs are applied, `Total` on `orders` may not be sufficient.  You may require `Cost` and `Quantity`.  Also, you may need additional charges applied to `Invoice`, e.g. shipping, handling.  In other words Invoice amount would be the total order Cost*Quantity + Shipping + Handling.

Comment: @Blazes An invoice can only have orders that is completed (eg: order.status = 1).

Comment: Thank you Wiseguy, I will do next time :)

Comment: @Blazes Cost*Quantity + Shipping + Handling already calculated to the 'orders.total' table.  Its calculate all the products/shipping/etc from 'order_items' table.  I have not included this example.

Comment: @user791022, or is that order.status=3? :D -- It sounds like your invoice.status is like (0:processing, 1:complete).  But, you could determine invoice.status when the invoice's order.status are all 3.

Comment: @Blazes I don't think you understand the concept. I will be processing each order individually weather this can be completed or cancel. After 1 month I can generate an invoice that is order.status 1 (from there I can pay client money or how much they owes me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks good.

The only thing I would add are some details like transaction id / check number to the payment table.  This way you keep all the payment details together.

Comment: That is a good idea, thank you. As you know an Invoice can contain 1 or more orders. What the best way to generate an invoice every 2 weeks? Using Cron Job that will scan the orders and then insert into invoice table and then 'update' order.invoice_id?  ....... or when I change the order status to 1 (orders.status = 1) then update orders.invoice_id (it check from invoice table first)

Comment: If you have the possibility of different clients being invoiced on different schedules, then create a client config table to hold the schedule.  But yes, use a cron job that kicks off every so often to see when invoices need to be generated.

Comment: Thanks @Chris Lively, Do you think I should have "OrderInvoice" Table which has both the OrderID and the invoice ID? So I don't need InvoiceID in the orders table.

Comment: @user791022: **IF** you have a situation in which you will allow partial payment of an order, then yes you need the OrderInvoice table.  An example is if the order amount was 1000, but you were going to bill them 500 now and 500 later.  However you should **NEVER** place the exact same "bill" across multiple invoices.  For example, if the order amount was 1000 and you invoiced 1000, then later created a new invoice for the exact same order for 1000.  Your accountant would scream at you if you allowed/did that.

Comment: Let say invoice has been genterated... then I found an error one of the order in the invoice (Incorrect Order total or orderID shouldnt be there).. that mean it will have to update tbl_invoice.amount again whenever I change the detail from the Order table.. do you get my point?

Comment: @user791022: There are several acceptable ways to adjust an invoice.  One is to simply make a modification and resend to the client.  The second is to permanently delete the existing one (keep an audit trail or you'll get in trouble) and create a new one.  Make sure the invoice itself reflects any payments that may have already been made.  Regardless, you will not keep multiple invoices covering amounts for the exact same thing.  An Auditor might consider that as a fraud indicator.

Comment: @user791022: I just ran across http://www.simpleinvoices.org.  You might check out how the site functions.

Comment: By "modification" - do you mean if I change the details in the order table and then automatically update to invoice (if it exist)? I can do this in PHP.

Comment: @user791022: A modification can be pretty much anything.  From giving discounts to fixing existing line item details.  The main thing here is IF the invoice has already been sent to the client, then you need to communicate to them when sending the updated invoice.  Otherwise there can be confusion on their side which is never a good thing.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, you have some serious issues here. Orders have mulitple items, invoices have multiple orders and payments may apply to mulitple orders and invoices. Orders may appear on multiple invoices (if they don't pay right aways which is common).

So what you need are linking tables. You should start with an ORDERINVOICE table which has both the order id and the invoice ID. Then an ORDERPAYMENT table with paymentid and Order id.

You also need to consider that in an ordering situation, you must record the details of the order as it occurred at the time. That means that while you should have the user_id to link to the current user, you should record the user's name, billing address and shipping addres as it was at the time of the order. You will need this information later to deal with any questions on the order. Further you need to ensure that you store the details of the order in a separate table called ORDERDETAILS which store the indivdual line items, the price at the time of the order and the name of the item ordered. You will need this for accounting reasons. You do not under any cuircumstances want to rely on a join to a product table to figure out the price of an order in the past. This will cause your finanacial records to be inaccurate.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion HLGEM, not sure if I understood clearly.. Could you post example of database design tables what you meant? Then I would understand better. thanks.

Comment: I understood what you meant for ORDERINVOICE table... Shouldnt ORDERPAYMENT table be with paymentid and InvoiceID (not OrderID)? ... In regarding to ordering situation to store record of the details username, billing address, product name, and product cost - There are 3 options to do this: versioning (type 2), history table (type 4) or duplicate data into orders table.. Which would be better?

Comment: I would say orderid and paymentID because you pay for the items on the orders not the invoice. If I invoiced you three times before you paid, the money would be credited to the order not the specific invoice. Certainly not to all three invoices. You can determine what is left unpaid for future invoices by order items that are not yet paid for. I prefer the data for the item to be in the order table. It isn't really duplicate information (it is the information at the time of the sale) so that isn't denormalizing anymore than having two orders with the same date wouldn't be duplicate data.

Comment: Ahh now I understood, thanks. Just a quick question. The price of item and the name of product always changed regular - there is no need for audit price history table or visioning data?

Comment: Always record the price and teh name of the product as it was at the time of order. If it changes in the future, that is irrelevant to the order. If you had not paid the invoice yet but were told the price was $100 wouldn't you be angry if you got an invoice of $150 because the price changed between the order and the invoice? If you record those details in an order detail table, you don't need a versioning table or price history table.

Comment: @HLGEM: I think the orderinvoice table is potentially a good idea, but not for the reason you specified.  If the invoice is unpaid, you don't generate a new invoice, you resend the existing one.  If you simply generate a new one your accountant may fire you as a client.  However, if you allow *partial payment* of an order, then yes multiple invoices can be allowed for a given order as long as the sum of all invoice amounts matches with the original order amount.

Comment: @HLGEM: Alternatively, you could allow partial payment of invoices..  It just depends on where you want to draw that line.

Answer (score 0):

It looks alright to me, this is what i would have done aswell.

(I would think a payment is linked with an order, but if you intended to link it to an invoice this is fine)

Regards,
MN

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about your requirements, so far so good.

Be sure to store your Invoice Status and Payment Type decodes in a lookup table so that they can be enforced in the database and don't have to rely on programmers coding it correctly.

Comment: I explain a bit more. Customer go online and select a store.. They place an order from the specific store. Their order is stored into orders and order_items table. Next month I want to generate invoice from a StoreID  that will display a list of orders (eg: orders.StoreID). In the invoice will tell me how much the store owes me or how much I need to pay. It calculate all the orders from orders.totals